# React Native "Reducers may not dispatch actions" when caling async function from componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new in React Native and I can't figure it out where I am making mistake. 
Namely in my React Native app when I am making an async function call I am getting

> *Reducers may not dispatch actions*

error.

here is the component where I am making the call

```
 componentDidMount(){
       this.initializeOverview().done();
  } 

   async initializeOverview() {
        await this.props.getExpensesSum();
    }
```

But if I call the same function without dispatch(getExpensesSumRequest()) in getExpensesSum() everithing is working just fine. The reason I am calling getExpensesSumRequest() is because I want to show loading indicator while waiting for data.

What confuses me even more is **When I call the getExpensesSum() with a button click it is working **

This is my action function which calls REST API and inside is the problematic getExpensesSumRequest() function.

```
export function getExpensesSum() {
    return (dispatch) => {

        **dispatch(getExpensesSumRequest())**

        return fetch(URL + "/api/expenses/sum/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json().then(json => ({
                json,
                response
            })))
            .then(({
                json,
                response
            }) => {
                if (response.ok === false) {    
                    return Promise.reject(response, json)
                }
                return json
            })
            .then(
                // success
                data => {
                    dispatch(getExpensesSumSuccess(data));
                },
                // failure
                (data) => dispatch(getExpensesSumFailure(data.status || 'Something failed'))
            ).catch((error) => console.warn("fetch error:", error))
    }
}
```

dispatched methods

```
export function getExpensesSumSuccess(expSum) {
    return {
        type: GET_EXPENSESSUM_SUCCESS,
        expSum
    }
}
export function getExpensesSumRequest() {
    return {
        type: GET_EXPENSESSUM_REQUEST,
    }
}
export function getExpensesSumFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: GET_EXPENSESSUM_FAILURE,
        error
    }
}
```

This is my reducer

```
import {
 GET_EXPENSESSUM_REQUEST,
 GET_EXPENSESSUM_SUCCESS,
 GET_EXPENSESSUM_FAILURE
} from '../actions/overview'

function expensesSum(state = {
  loadingExpensesSum: false, 
   expensesSum: {'Sum':0}   
}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_EXPENSESSUM_REQUEST:
      return {
        loadingExpensesSum: true, // Show a loading indicator.
        expensesSum:{'Sum':0}
      }
    case GET_EXPENSESSUM_FAILURE:
      return {
        loadingExpensesSum: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    case GET_EXPENSESSUM_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loadingExpensesSum: false,
        expensesSum: action.expSum,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default expensesSum
```

I am using react-redux to bind my actions to my dispatchers like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    getExpensesSum: () => dispatch(getExpensesSum()),

  };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name: state.user.name,
    expensesSum:state.expensesSum.Sum,

  };
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

P.S. here is the stack trace

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDEBA.png)

[device stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLjZJ.png)

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when that error occurs?

Comment: I added two pictures with stack traces
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLjZJ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDEBA.png

Answer (score 0):

My issue was using a dispatch after an asynchronous eventListener was triggered.

The method [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators) explained [here](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/4-ways-to-dispatch-actions-with-redux) did not helped.

Somehow, the redux backend does not recognize the dispatch actor, after a little bit. This fixes the error. In `actions.js`:

```
const SET_SOMETHING='SET_SOMETHING'

export const doSomething = () => {
  return {
    type:SET_SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Component using the action:

```
import { doSomething } from './actions.js'

class Foo extends React.Component { 
  componentDidMount() {

    const fn = ()=>{
      // this gives the error --> this.props.do()

      // this works
      setTimeout(()=>{this.props.do()},100)
    }
    document.addEventListener( 'event', fn )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {  
  return {
    do: id => {
      dispatch(doSomething())
    }
}

...
```